# Hide Fab inside Constraint layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button

I've tried to hide a floating action button inside a constraint layout container

but it didn't work
I've tried

`fab.visibility=View.Gone`

and

`fab.hide()`

but both of them not worked

btw I've used google material library and constraint layout

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'`

`implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'`

and this is a layout formation

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_container">

        <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline/>
    
    <com.imangazaliev.circlemenu.CircleMenu/> // I mean this one it's custom view that extends FloatActionButton

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

so how to solve this issue and thanks for all.

Comment: Where you have write gone code?Please share code also so anyone can understand the issue.

Comment: @NadimAnsari I've edited my question 
Is it clear now?

Comment: add fab code also and code where you have hide the fab.

Answer (score 1):

use coordinateLayout as root.then get params.

> CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();

setAnchorId

> params.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID)

and

> fab.setLayoutParams(params)

finally

> fab.show() or hide()

Comment: I know a Coordinator layout way but I want to hide fa while constraint layout is the root.